# Android active camera detect

Tags: android, android-camera, hardware

I develop an application.  I use a library before applying. The camera turns on when the application starts, but I do not turn on the camera. What I want is how I can find the open camera. I want to find the camera that is open and close it.

Thanks!

For example:

```
Camera mCamera; 
if (getActiveCameraFind() != null)
mCamera = activeCamera;
```

Comment: can u explain me in detail?

Comment: You mean you want to have singleton Camera class instance or something else? Please elaborate

Comment: Elaborate more, we cannot read your mind :)

Comment: I am so sorry :) Many thanks for your answers.

I use a library before applying. The camera turns on when the application starts, but I do not turn on the camera. What I want is how I can find the open camera. I want to find the camera that is open and close it.